# Generate a new dataframe based on old datafarame and store it in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

My original dataframe is shown below:

```
     H1 H2  H3  H4  H5
A1   1  0   0   1   0
A2   1  0   0   1   0
A3   1  1   0   0   0
A4   1  0   1   0   0
A5   1  0   1   0   1
A6   1  1   1   0   0
A7   1  0   1   0   0
A8   1  0   1   0   1
A9   1  1   1   0   0
```

I have two dataframe that are stored in the form of list

```
#list_of_dataframes
[
     H1 H2  H3  H4  H5
A2   1  0   0   1   0
A3   1  1   0   0   0
A4   1  0   1   0   0
A5   1  0   1   0   1
A6   1  1   1   0   0,
     H1 H2  H3  H4  H5
A1   1  0   0   1   0
A3   1  1   0   0   0
A7   1  0   1   0   0
A8   1  0   1   0   1
A9   1  1   1   0   0]
```

I want to generate an output dataframe that should store in the form of list. My output dataframe should keep all row index and column index of the original dataframe. But for the new dataframe that will store in the form of list it should should in the list of dataframes if the corresponding row is present in it, it should place 1 in the original dataframe, otherwise it should place 0.

```
   # list of Output dataframe 
   [
        H1 H2  H3  H4  H5
  A1    0  0   0   0   0
  A2    1  1   1   1   1
  A3    1  1   1   1   1
  A4    1  1   1   1   1
  A5    1  1   1   1   1
  A6    1  1   1   1   1
  A7    0  0   0   0   0
  A8    0  0   0   0   0
  A9    0  0   0   0   0,
  
           H1   H2  H3  H4  H5
      A1   1    1   1   1   1
      A2   0    0   0   0   0
      A3   1    1   1   1   1
      A4   0    0   0   0   0
      A5   0    0   0   0   0
      A6   0    0   0   0   0
      A7   1    1   1   1   1
      A8   1    1   1   1   1
      A9   1    1   1   1   1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) the input `df` with each of the *DataFrames* held in your list :

```
def delta(dfl, dfr):
    tmp = dfl.align(dfr)[1]
    tmp[tmp.notnull()] = 1
    out = tmp.fillna(0, downcast="infer")
    return out

out_list = [delta(in_df, df) for df in lst] # assuming lst in the list of your dfs
```

Another variant with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)/[`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) :

```
out_list = [in_df.eq(df).replace({True: 1, False: 0}) for df in lst]
```

Output :

```
[    H1  H2  H3  H4  H5
 A1   0   0   0   0   0
 A2   1   1   1   1   1
 A3   1   1   1   1   1
 A4   1   1   1   1   1
 A5   1   1   1   1   1
 A6   1   1   1   1   1
 A7   0   0   0   0   0
 A8   0   0   0   0   0
 A9   0   0   0   0   0,
     H1  H2  H3  H4  H5
 A1   1   1   1   1   1
 A2   0   0   0   0   0
 A3   1   1   1   1   1 # <-- shows that you have a typo in your expected output
 A4   0   0   0   0   0
 A5   0   0   0   0   0
 A6   0   0   0   0   0
 A7   1   1   1   1   1
 A8   1   1   1   1   1
 A9   1   1   1   1   1]
```